# How to convert characters beyond ASCII range to HTML entities

Tags: java

Currently I'm running the replace like this:

```
    .replace("®", "&reg")
    .replace("°", "&deg")
    .replace("™", "&#0153;")
    .replace("©", "&copy;")
```

But that relies on a lot to go right before I get to this point.  What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[org.apache.commons.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) looks like it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this utils class: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

In your particular case it will be `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(...)`

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String)